# Single Positional Indexer is out of Bounds

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
stats_list = ['GP', 'RECs', 'REC Yds', 'REC TDs', 'MS RECs', 'MS REC Yards', 'MS REC TDs', 'DOM']

for column in stats_list:
    mask = TE_df.columns.str.startswith(column)
    TE_df[f'{column} Last'] = TE_df.loc[:, mask].ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

Which is a straight copy paste from another piece of code (just with the name of the df changed). On the other code this works no problem, but on this code it keeps bringing back the error 'single positional indexer is out of bounds (associates it with the last line).

I think this is something to do with the 'iloc[:, -1]' part of the code, but I've no idea why. My understanding is that this should just add a column to the end of the df which is a ffill of the specified columns. All of the other questions on here seem to have the root cause of the issue being that the code is calling a column that doesn't exist (a positive number as the indexer) which I understand, but I don't understand how the -1 figure can be considered out of bounds.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this however just spit-balling that `-1` would indeed be out of bounds if 0 elements in list.  Can you verify this is not the case?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, do you mean that it might be that the stats_list might contain a column name that doesn't exist in my dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is no match column, so `TE_df.loc[:, mask]` return empty DataFrame, so `iloc[:, -1]` failed.

Test if there is 2 or more `True`s values (it means matching 2 or more columns) and only then run code:

```
for column in stats_list:
    mask = TE_df.columns.str.startswith(column)
    if mask.sum() > 1:
        TE_df[f'{column} Last'] = TE_df.loc[:, mask].ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

Comment: Ah Ok - are you thinking that perhaps some elements of my stats_list aren't in the dataframe with this?

Comment: @BewareTheHare - yes, exactly. Test by `stats_list = ['aaa','GP']`

Comment: Ah OK perfect thanks - that seems like an odd error message to get back though right? I would have expected the error to have appeared elsewhere in the code to say that it's not found. Complete beginner so maybe I just don't understand how the code works well enough

Comment: The code does now work though which is great - thankyou so much for the help!